# Android Data Binding - convert map fragment to SupportMapFragment automatically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-databinding, supportmapfragment

Android Data Binding converts views to fields automatically, but it doesn't support casting by default. Here is my fragment view, and I need it as `SupportMapFragment` not just `Fragment`.

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:context=".ui.views.map.MapFragment" />
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score -4):

What if you access it the tradicional way:

`mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);`